# Using max/aggregate functions

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, sybase

I'm struggling with SQL aggregate functions and find it difficult to find any use for them as the rules are so strict. Can anybody tell me why the first query below doesn't work, and why the second query gives the same rows, just in a different order? What I'm trying to do is find the date and location of the top value for the BORROWER_ID of 10.

For the first query I would expect just a single row to be returned. This is running on Sybase but I assume other versions of SQL would be similar.

The problem as I see it is there's no simple way of telling SQL that we want to return various columns of a row for a single maximum column amongst them.

```
1> select CREATE_LOCATION, max(CREATE_DATE) from LOAN where BORROWER_ID=10 group by CREATE_DATE
2> go
CREATE_LOCATION
--------------- -------------------------------
SSU                         Jun 18 2001  9:28AM
SSU                         Feb 12 2001 11:49AM
SSU                         Sep 10 2000 10:43AM
SSU                         Sep 10 2000 10:43AM
SSU                         Sep 10 2000 10:43AM
SSU                         Sep 10 2000 10:43AM
SSU                         Sep 10 2000 10:43AM

(7 rows affected)
1> select CREATE_LOCATION, CREATE_DATE from LOAN where BORROWER_ID=10
2> go
CREATE_LOCATION CREATE_DATE
--------------- -------------------------------
SSU                         Sep 10 2000 10:43AM
SSU                         Sep 10 2000 10:43AM
SSU                         Sep 10 2000 10:43AM
SSU                         Sep 10 2000 10:43AM
SSU                         Sep 10 2000 10:43AM
SSU                         Jun 18 2001  9:28AM
SSU                         Feb 12 2001 11:49AM

(7 rows affected)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem as I see it is there's no simple way of telling SQL that we want to return various columns of a row for a single maximum column amongst them.

There is a simple way.  It just doesn't use aggregation.  Remember:  The purpose of aggregation is to combine multiple rows generated by the `FROM` clause into single rows in the result set.

Instead, use `order by`:

```
select l.*
from loan l
where borrower_id = 10
order by create_date desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

In Sybase, you would use `top (1)` instead of `fetch`:

```
select top (1) l.*
from loan l
where borrower_id = 10
order by create_date desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yous  should use a different group by

```
 select CREATE_LOCATION, max(CREATE_DATE) 
 from LOAN where BORROWER_ID=10 
 group by CREATE_LOCATION
```

You should not use the same column in aggregation function and in group by clause  this is the wrong way for use aggregation  ...

you should use aggregation function on different columns respected  the columns in group  by clause..

Th group by clause simply tell to the db engine respect which column you want perform aggreagtion

Comment: Thanks. The answers above are very helpful. Grouping by CREATE_LOCATION gives a more accurate result but isn't what I want because it gives a value for each location and all I want is the most recent date. I will use Gordon L's suggestion.